# Sqlalchemy: How to manage multiple tables (Python)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to create four tables. First table include the "Users", second include "Group Name", the second table should be related to "Users" table. Third table include "Groups Columns Data" which is related to "Group" table, and finally the fourth table is "Group Borrow Lending Data" which is also linked to third table i.e "Groups".

But it's throwing an error when I try to get specific username.

> TypeError: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't compare a
> collection to an object or collection; use contains() to test for
> membership.

```py
@v1.get("/get-specific-groups/{group_name}", tags=["GROUP"])
def get_specific_groups(group_name: str, current_user: CreateGroupSchema = Depends(get_current_user), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return db.query(User, Group, GroupColumnsData).join(GroupColumnsData).filter(Group.owner_username == current_user.get("username")).all()
```

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(140), nullable=False)

    groups = relationship("Group", backref="owner")


class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = "groups"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    group_name = Column(String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)

    owner_username = Column(String, ForeignKey("users.username"), default=User.username)
    group_username = relationship("GroupColumnsData", backref="group_owner")


class GroupColumnsData(Base):
    __tablename__ = "groupsColumnsData"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    payee_name = Column(String(60))
    item_name = Column(String(100))
    amount_spent = Column(Integer)

    owner_group = Column(String, ForeignKey("groups.group_name"), default=Group.group_name)


class GroupBorrowLendingData(Base):
    __tablename__ = "groupsBorrowLendingData"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    lender = Column(String(60))
    money_borrowed = Column(Integer)
    borrower = Column(String(60))

    owner_group = Column(String, ForeignKey("groups.group_name"), default=Group.group_name)
```

Comment: it seems to be saying instead of using .filter you need to use .contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Following code worked!

```
@v1.get("/get-specific-groups/{group_name}", tags=["GROUP"])
def get_specific_groups(group_name: str, current_user: CreateGroupSchema = Depends(get_current_user), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return db.query(Group).filter(Group.owner_username == current_user.get("username")).filter(Group.group_name.match(group_name)).all()
```